# aws load data from s3 to rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have a question regarding technical architecture on AWS.

**Situation:**
There are couple of sales units (each has Database in different location not connected with each other). Business requirement is that sales units place aggregated data in csv files which later will be loaded to report database.

I know already that I will need to do complex ETL processes (I work on SSIS), schedule jobs, write procedures and execute them automatically. Basically everything that MSSQL Server does + Data tools.

**Question:**
Is it possible to load data securely to S3, then load to RDS (mssql) via ETL process exclusively on AWS? Is it a good idea? Can AWS GLUE/DataPipeline do the job?

If so please name the services with links how to do those tasks if possible.

Thank you for opinions.

Comment: This link should really clarify what you are trying to acomplish [Importing Data into an Amazon RDS MySQL DB Instance from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html). You can create a new database form a backup on S3, not attach to an existing one.

That being said if you are using SSIS I don't see why you shouldn't be able to get the csv file from a S3 bucket with proper authentication and then run you import process.

Comment: 1. Question is: can I accomplish those tasks using exclusively AWS
2. DB will be MSSQL not MYSQL.
3. I want to get rid of SSIS -> in favour of GLUE/Data Pipeline (?)

Comment: Using [Amazon Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) would be a good option. I prefer the control of an ETL tool, I run Pentaho Data Integration on an EC2 instance and works perfectly, specially with MSSQLServer

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

On a high level, within the data pipeline you would need -

1. S3 data node - Your input data
2. Activity - Any transformation you want to do
3. Resource - either EMR or EC2 depending on what resources/software is needed.
4. RDS data node - Output for the process, your RDS database.

In addition to the above, you can also setup retries, alerts for failures, success etc.

You can refer the AWS documents here - 
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/data-pipeline/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html

Comment: can we do S3-> RDS Oracle? In the templates, i cannot see for Oracle. only MYSQL amd SQL is there.